# How to replace "->"?

Tags: clojure

I wonder, how can I replace this without "->"?

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (->
    "http://www.fsdfdsfds.com" URL. html-resource
     print))
```

I tried this and it didn't print anything:

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (print(URL. html-resource "http://www.fsdfdsfds.com"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace it like so:

```
(print (html-resource (URL. "http://www.fsdfdsfds.com")))
```

The way you have it, you are passing 2 args to URL.  The thread-first macro passes your url string to URL., then html-resource, then to `print`.